# java how to make character follow Pathfinding

Tags: java, path-finding, a-star, mousemove

After few days trying to understand and coding the A star pathfinding alogrithm wich i do understand now.
I finally code it and make it work

so now what i would like to know is how can i make my hero follow the path. 
any code snipet or example would be appreciated.
 i had an idea on how to do it but it didn't work unfortunately Thank you in advance.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;


 public class GameBoard extends JPanel implements ActionListener,Runnable{
 private Thread game;
 private volatile boolean running=false;
 Map m; 
 Player hero;
 Path path;
 AstarPathfinder p1;
 int targetX,targetY;
 int dir=0;
 public GameBoard ()
 {
   //setSize(620,720);
   setBackground(Color.gray);
   setFocusable(true);
   requestFocus();
   hero=new Player();
   hero.setX(3/36);
   hero.setY(3/36);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
           {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            handleMousePressed(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    });
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                       // System.out.println("mouse dragged");
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            //handleMouseMoved(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    });

}

private void handleMousePressed(int x, int y)
    {   
    targetX=x /= 36;
    targetY=y/= 36;
            p1=new  AstarPathfinder ();
            path=p1.PathFinding(hero.getX()/36, hero.getY()/36, targetX,targetY);
            repaint();
    }




public void startGame()
{
     if(game==null|| !running)
   {     
               game=new Thread(this);
               game.start();
               running=true;                        


   }   
}
@Override
  public void run()
{
   while(running)
   {

        moveit();

        try {

            Thread.sleep(5);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GameBoard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

   }
}

public void moveit()
{ 
    for(int x=0; x<14; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<14;y++)
        {

                                     if (path != null)
                                   {

                 if (path.contains(x,y)) 
                                         {
                                            if(path.getX(x)<hero.getX()){
                                             hero.x-=1;
                                             }
                                             else if(path.getX(x)> hero.getX())
                                             {
                                               hero.x+=1;
                                             }


                                              if(path.getY(y)< hero.getY())
                                              {
                                                hero.y-=1;
                                              }
                                              else  if(path.getY(y)> hero.getY())
                                              {

                                               hero.y+=1;
                                              } 


               }
            }
        }
      }

   }
   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
   m=new Map();     
   m.OpenFile();
   m.ReadFile();
   m.CloseFile();

    for(int y=0; y<14; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<14; x++)
       {

           if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("g"))
           {
              g.drawImage(m.getGrass(), x*36, y*36, this); 
           }

           if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("b"))
           {
                g.drawImage(m.getBlock(), x*36, y*36, this); 
           }
           if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("d"))
           {
                g.drawImage(m.getDirt(), x*36, y*36, this);
           }
           if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("t"))
           {
                g.drawImage(m.getGOAL(), x*36, y*36, this);



           }


                           if (path != null)
                             {

                      if (path.contains(x,y)) 
                                           {
                                                    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        g.fillRect(x*36, y*36,19,19);
                                           }

                }


       }
    }

 }
  @Override
  public void addNotify()
  {//build in jpanel method
    super.addNotify();
   ///donc quand le jpanel est en marche partir le jeu.
    startGame();



 }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }


 }
```

end my entity class

```
public class Entity {

int x, y, dx, dy;

public Entity() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
}

public Entity(int xe, int ye) {
    this.x = xe;
    this.y = ye;
}

public int getDx() {
    return dx;
}

public void setDx(int dx) {
    this.dx = dx;
}

public int getDy() {
    return dy;
}

public void setDy(int dy) {
    this.dy = dy;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

class player

```
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Image;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

 public class Player extends Entity {
 private Image p;
public Player()
{
   super(); 
    p=new ImageIcon("C:/Java/Prj/src/images/player.png").getImage();
}

 public Image getPlayer()
{
    return p;
}
/* public void move(char d)
 {
     if(d=='d')
     this.x+=this.dx;
     this.y+=this.dy;
 }*/
public void drawPlayer(Graphics g)
{

   g.drawImage(this.p,this.x,this.y,null);

}
}
```

my Astarpath class

```
enter code here

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.LinkedList;
  import java.util.List;

 public class AstarPathfinder {

LinkedList<Node> closed = new LinkedList();
LinkedList<Node> open = new LinkedList();
int newH, newF, newG, ndlength = 14;
Node[][] nodes = new Node[ndlength][ndlength];
Path path;

public AstarPathfinder() {


    for (int i = 0; i < ndlength; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ndlength; j++) {
            nodes[i][j] = new Node(i, j);
        }
    }

}

public Path PathFinding(int sx, int sy, int tx, int ty) {
    Node start = nodes[sx][sy];
    Node target = nodes[tx][ty];
    start.g = 0;
    start.h = estimateCost(start, target);
    start.f = start.g + start.h;

    start.parent = null;
    open.add(start);



    while (open.size() != 0) {

        Node current = null;

        if (open.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("aucune route/no possible road");
        }


        current = getCurrent();
        if (current == target) {
            //System.out.println("reach the target: " + target);
            break;
        }
        open.remove(current);
        closed.add(current);




        List<Node> neighbors = (List<Node>) createNeighbors(current);

        for (int k = 0; k < neighbors.size(); k++) {

            Node neighborNode = neighbors.get(k);
            if (closed.contains(neighborNode)) {
                continue;
            }
            newG = current.g + 10;// + estimateDistance(current, neighborNode);
            newH = estimateCost(neighborNode, target);
            newF = newG + newH;

            if (newG < neighborNode.g) {

                neighborNode.parent = current;
                neighborNode.h = newH;
                neighborNode.g = newG;
                neighborNode.f = newF;

            }
            if ((!open.contains(neighborNode)) && !(closed.contains(neighborNode))) {

                open.add(neighborNode);
                neighborNode.parent = current;
                neighborNode.h = newH;
                neighborNode.g = newG;
                neighborNode.f = newF;
            }
        }//endloopfor

    }//end while

    path = new Path();
    Node target2 = target;
    while (target2 != start) {
        path.prependStep(target2.x, target2.y);
        target2 = target2.parent;

    }

    path.prependStep(start.x, start.y);
    return path;
}

public int estimateCost(Node node1, Node node2) {
    float resultat;
    float dx = node1.x - node2.x;
    float dy = node1.y - node2.y;
    resultat = Math.abs((dx * dx) + (dy + dy));
    resultat += resultat * 0.001;
    return (int) resultat;
}

/**
 * cette fonction perment de retourner le noeud courant 
 * @return 
 */
private Node getCurrent() {
    Node currentNode = null;
    int maxintf = open.size();
    int minf = 1000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxintf; i++) {
        Node node = (Node) open.get(i);
        if (node.f < minf) {
            currentNode = node;

        }
    }
    return currentNode;
}

/**
 * Fontion permettant de trouver les 8 voisins
 */
private List<Node> createNeighbors(Node cnodes) {
    int i = cnodes.x;
    int j = cnodes.y;
    List<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<Node>();
    int indiceup = cnodes.x - 1;
    int indicedown = cnodes.x + 1;
    int indiceleft = cnodes.y - 1;
    int indiceright = cnodes.y + 1;
    if (indiceup > -1) {
        neighbors.add(nodes[indiceup][cnodes.y]);
    }
    if (indicedown < 14) {
        neighbors.add(nodes[indicedown][cnodes.y]);
    }
    if (indiceleft > -1) {
        neighbors.add(nodes[cnodes.x][indiceleft]);
    }
    if (indiceright < 14) {
        neighbors.add(nodes[cnodes.x][indiceright]);
    }
    return neighbors;
}

public class Node {

    int g = 0;//cost
    int h = 0;//heuristic
    int f = g;//f+g
    Node parent;
    int x, y;
    boolean visited;

    public Node(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.visited = false;
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    }

    public int getF() {
        return f;
    }

    public void setF(int f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public int getG() {
        return g;
    }

    public void setG(int g) {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public int getH() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(int h) {
        this.h = h;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    }
    }
```

and here's the path class which i got from coke and code website. i build the whole    thing from scratch i am trying to understand of course i will retype everything once i do understand  :) sorry for the crappy code

path class

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Path {
/** The list of steps building up this path */
private ArrayList steps = new ArrayList();

/**
 * Create an empty path
 */
public Path() {

}

/**
 * Get the length of the path, i.e. the number of steps
 * 
 * @return The number of steps in this path
 */
public int getLength() {
    return steps.size();
}

/**
 * Get the step at a given index in the path
 * 
 * @param index The index of the step to retrieve. Note this should
 * be >= 0 and < getLength();
 * @return The step information, the position on the map.
 */
public Step getStep(int index) {
    return (Step) steps.get(index);
}

/**
 * Get the x coordinate for the step at the given index
 * 
 * @param index The index of the step whose x coordinate should be retrieved
 * @return The x coordinate at the step
 */
public int getX(int index) {
    return getStep(index).x;
}

/**
 * Get the y coordinate for the step at the given index
 * 
 * @param index The index of the step whose y coordinate should be retrieved
 * @return The y coordinate at the step
 */
public int getY(int index) {
    return getStep(index).y;
}

/**
 * Append a step to the path.  
 * 
 * @param x The x coordinate of the new step
 * @param y The y coordinate of the new step
 */
public void appendStep(int x, int y) {
    steps.add(new Step(x,y));
}

/**
 * Prepend a step to the path.  
 * 
 * @param x The x coordinate of the new step
 * @param y The y coordinate of the new step
 */
public void prependStep(int x, int y) {
    steps.add(0, new Step(x, y));
}

/**
 * Check if this path contains the given step
 * 
 * @param x The x coordinate of the step to check for
 * @param y The y coordinate of the step to check for
 * @return True if the path contains the given step
 */
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    return steps.contains(new Step(x,y));
}

/**
 * A single step within the path
 * 
 * @author Kevin Glass
 */
public class Step {
    /** The x coordinate at the given step */
    private int x;
    /** The y coordinate at the given step */
    private int y;

    /**
     * Create a new step
     * 
     * @param x The x coordinate of the new step
     * @param y The y coordinate of the new step
     */
    public Step(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /**
     * Get the x coordinate of the new step
     * 
     * @return The x coodindate of the new step
     */
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * Get the y coordinate of the new step
     * 
     * @return The y coodindate of the new step
     */
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * @see Object#hashCode()
     */
    public int hashCode() {
        return x*y;
    }

    /**
     * @see Object#equals(Object)
     */
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Step) {
            Step o = (Step) other;

            return (o.x == x) && (o.y == y);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: If your A* algorithm gives you the optimal path, or even the first choice for that optimal path, then that's what your  "hero" should use.  Without any more info about either your A* implementation or the problem it is being applied to, can't say much more than that.

Comment: You should probably try posting the code relevant to where you tried, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Some general comments:

Your code is quite hard to read. 
Please try to use meaningfull variable names in the future (or at least comment on those that are not). For example: what is Dx?

Also: hero.drawPlayer(g) seems to be independent of the loop it is in. So why put it in the loop? The player will be drawn way more often than needed.
It seems that the map is loaded (from a file!) every time paint() is called. That seems unneccesary.

To your problem:

Are you sure that this line: targetX=x /= 36; is correct? 
You did not include the PathFinding class so I assume that you are sure that it returns the correct path (you printed it out or something)?

In your moveit() loop:
path.getX(x)
That just does not look right. I do not know your implementation of Path class, but I would assume that it is some kind of list. On one call of moveit() you want to move the player to the next element of that list, right? Or at least in the direction of that element. But you never call path.getFirst or path.getNext, you seem to use all the elements of the path.

// edit: as to how to do that:

either add a pop method to your path:

```
public Step popStep() {
    Step temp = steps.get(0);
    steps.remove(0);
    return temp;
}
```

And use that or add a counter somewhere (in case you need the full path later).

And then change your move method to:

```
public void moveit() {
    Step nextStep = path.popStep();
    hero.setX(nextStep.getX());
    hero.setY(nextStep.getY());
}
```

This way the player will always move to the next step in your path.
Also, maybe you want to wait more than 5 milliseconds between calls to move.

Comment: I do not think Zéychin requested all code (only the one relevant to the problem). Anyways,  as i said in moveit you should only move the player to the next Step in the path. Also i would recheck the whole dividing and multiplying with 36 part of your code. eg 3/36 cast to int is 0.

Comment: @3rdosye I am not quite sure what your problem is with that. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do. I edited my original answer anyways to what I think you want.